# Passing/updating global variables (e.g. group vars) from within the playbook?

Tags: ansible, global-variables

I there any way to pass/update group variables from within the playbook task?
I need to define variables based on results of some commands from one host to use them for other roles and tasks. I know about set_fact but it stores variable as local variable so that I need to address specific host to get it but hostname/address of this host can vary.
Googling and reading docs.ansible.com doesn't help still.

UPD: there is 2 different roles that playing tasks one after another and I need to pass variables between plays.

Comment: you can register the variable from one host group and access the same variable in another host group.

Comment: @error404 getting an error:
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'var_name' is undefined. Looks like it's not working like that. Maybe it wll work if there will be one playbook with hosts defined within but there is 2 different roles that playing tasks one after another.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to use ansible modules lineinfile, blockinfile, template, and ini_file to update [group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#working-with-inventory).

For example the play below

```
- hosts: test_jails
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_groupvar_file: "{{  inventory_dir }}/group_vars/test_jails.yml"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_last_run
    - block:
        - command: date "+%F %T"
          register: result
        - lineinfile:
            path: "{{ my_groupvar_file }}"
            regexp: "^my_last_run: "
            line: "my_last_run: {{ result.stdout }}"
            backup: yes
          delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

with group variables group_vars/test_jails.yml

```
my_last_run: 2019-04-19 11:51:00
```

gives (abridged):

```
> ansible-playbook test1.yml
PLAY [test_jails]
TASK [debug] 
ok: [test_01] => {
"my_last_run": "2019-04-19 11:51:00"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
"my_last_run": "2019-04-19 11:51:00"
}
ok: [test_02] => {
"my_last_run": "2019-04-19 11:51:00"
}
TASK [command]
changed: [test_01]
TASK [lineinfile]
changed: [test_01 -> localhost]
PLAY RECAP
test_01                    : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_02                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

> cat group_vars/test_jails.yml
my_last_run: 2019-04-19 11:56:51
```

Comment: Many thanks!
That's the only real solution which has worked for me and it isn't mentioned anywhere. I can only add that it'll be better to use `{{ inventory_dir }}` instead of `{{ playbook_dir }}` because playbooks and hosts file not always located together.

Comment: Right. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: I want to add also that updating group vars with regex isn't the best practice because it can cause issues.
When I wrote a large playbook where the same hosts group was used several times during the play with various tasks it revealed that group vars for this hosts group loading only at the beginning of the play. They doesn't update when I change group vars file and then execute another task with this host group. As a result this task fails because it takes old variables.
So it'll be better to use separate vars file to update it with regex and load it inside the task then with
`vars_files:`